# Kubernetes Cluster kubeadm reset one node is cluster does not have external IP

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

Trying to fix something, I think I broke it worse.
I ran kubeadm reset on a node
join it back to the cluster

EXTERNAL-IP shows NONE
Other nodes INTERNAL-IP matches EXTERNAL-IP

kubectl get node -o wide
3 Control Plane,
EXTERNAL-IP shows NONE
[image]

Curious how I can have the rejoin node have the internal-IP match the external-IP

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

was able to resolve the External missing per the screenshot playing around with the join,

kind: JoinConfiguration
nodeRegistration:
criSocket: /var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
kubeletExtraArgs:
cloud-provider: external